# Dropdown list using mustache js template

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

Ajax response:

```
case 1:[{"id":1,"value":"sub 1"},{"id":2,"value":"sub 2"},{"id":3,"value":"sub 3"}]
case 2:[{"id":1,"value":"sub 1"},{"id":2,"value":"sub 2"},{"id":3,"value":"sub 3"}]
```

Mustache template:

```
<div class="form-group" id="submenu_list">
<script id="dropDownList" type="text/template"> 
<select class="form-control" name="sub_menu" id="sub_menu" >
    {{#.}}
             <option value="{{id}}">{{value}}</option>
    {{/.}}         
</select>
</script>
</div>
```

Mustache render code:

```
var template = $("#dropDownList").html();
subMenuList = Mustache.render(template, data); 
$("#submenu_list").html(subMenuList);
```

I am getting the above response on click of another dropdown and trying to populate the above dropdown from the json response but It is not working! please tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer I am putting js template inside the

```
<div class="form-group" id="submenu_list"></div>
```

So rendering the template once, template is replaced by html code, so now I am putting template outside the above div.

```
<div class="form-group" id="submenu_list"></div>
<script id="dropDownList" type="text/template"> 
<select class="form-control" name="sub_menu" id="sub_menu" >
    {{#.}}
             <option value="{{id}}">{{value}}</option>
    {{/.}}         
</select>
</script>
```

Hahaha! my bad